# (django)TemplateDoesNotExist at /

Tags: python, django

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('calc.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'tmpl/home.html')
```

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'tmpl')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
```

**calc/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home')

]
```

folder structure:

[image: 1]

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: django in its stacktrace also gives which paths were tried to find templates, maybe use that info

Comment: show `calc.urls`

Comment: In `settings.py`: `print(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'tmpl'))`  Does that exist?

Comment: print(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'tmpl')) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your settings.py inside `TEMPLATES` do:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'top', 'tmpl')]
```

and in views.py

```
return render(request, 'home.html')
```